# Checking if column headers match PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

df1:

```
      ID  Open High Low  
       1  64   66   52
```

df2

```
      ID Open High  Volume
      1   33   45   30043
```

I want to write a function that checks if the column headers are matching/the same as columns in df1.

IF not we get a message telling us what column is missing.

Example of the message given these dataframes:

```
  "The column 'Low' is not selected in df2. The column 'Volume' is not selected in df1'
```

I want a generalized code that can work for any given dataframe.

Is this possible on python?

Comment: `df1.columns.difference(df2.columns)` will give you the collumns that are in df1 that are not in df2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have access to the column names via `.columns` and then use set operations to check what you want:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [1],
        "Open": [64],
        "High": [66],
        "Low": [52]
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [1],
        "Open": [33],
        "High": [45],
        "Volume": [30043]
    }
)

df1_columns = set(df1.columns)
df2_columns = set(df2.columns)

common_columns = df1_columns & df2_columns

df1_columns_only = df1_columns - common_columns
df2_columns_only = df2_columns - common_columns

print("Columns only available in df1", df1_columns_only)
print("Columns only available in df2", df2_columns_only)
```

And it gives the expected output:

```
Columns only available in df1 {'Low'}
Columns only available in df2 {'Volume'}
```